# How do I set the disableCopyInSubstring System Property from the String class in Java?

Tags: java, string, jvm

This is a snippet from the String class of IBM / Websphere Java 1.8.64

```
    /**
    *  This is a System property to disable copying the String when offset is non-zero in {@link #substring(int)}} and {@link #substring(int, int)}}
    */
   static boolean disableCopyInSubstring;
```

I want to set the property like so.

```
System.setProperty("java.lang.String.disableCopyInSubstring", "true");
```

But, apparently that isn't the correct way to set it because I'm debugging into the String class and that variable is still showing `false`.

Adding a larger snippet from the String class I'm using.  This is IBM's Websphere Java 1.8.64.  When I asked I had originally thought I was using Oracle's Java.  Here is the snippet from that variable and up.

```
package java.lang;

/*
 * Licensed Materials - Property of IBM,
 *     Copyright IBM Corp. 1998, 2016  All Rights Reserved
 */

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.Iterator;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

/**
 * Strings are objects which represent immutable arrays of
 * characters.
 *
 * @author      OTI
 * @version     initial
 *
 * @see         StringBuffer
 */

public final class String implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    // DO NOT CHANGE OR MOVE THIS LINE
    // IT MUST BE THE FIRST THING IN THE INITIALIZATION
    private static final boolean STRING_OPT_IN_HW = StrCheckHWAvailable();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6849794470754667710L;

    /**
     * CaseInsensitiveComparator compares Strings ignoring the case of the
     * characters.
     */
    private static final class CaseInsensitiveComparator implements Comparator<String>, Serializable {
        static final long serialVersionUID = 8575799808933029326L;

        /**
         * Compare the two objects to determine
         * the relative ordering.
         *
         * @param       o1  an Object to compare
         * @param       o2  an Object to compare
         * @return      an int < 0 if object1 is less than object2,
         *              0 if they are equal, and > 0 if object1 is greater
         *
         * @exception   ClassCastException when objects are not the correct type
         */
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        }
    };

    /**
     * A Comparator which compares Strings ignoring the case of the
     * characters.
     */
    public static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER = new CaseInsensitiveComparator();
    private static final char[] ascii;
    private static String[] stringArray;
    private static final int stringArraySize = 10;
    private static class UnsafeHelpers {
        public final static long valueFieldOffset = getValueFieldOffset();
        static long getValueFieldOffset() {
            try { return sun.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe().objectFieldOffset(String.class.getDeclaredField("value")); }
            catch (NoSuchFieldException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }
    }
    /**
     *  This is a System property to enable copy in {@link #String(String)}}
     */
    static boolean enableCopy;

    /**
    *  This is a System property to disable copying the String when offset is non-zero in {@link #substring(int)}} and {@link #substring(int, int)}}
    */
   static boolean disableCopyInSubstring;
```

Comment: Are you sure this snippet comes from java.lang.String ? I can't find this attribute anywhere..

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or other vendor?

Comment: I can't find it in 1.8.77. But since you found the variable in the source code, search in the source code where it is being changed.

Comment: I added more of the String class.  At first I overlooked it, but I'm using IBM's Websphere Java 1.8.64.

Answer (score 1):

To set this System Property set the following property as so in the VM arguments.

```
-Djava.lang.string.substring.nocopy=true
```

This has solved the issue.  I've only seen this issue with IBM's Java implementation.